# How to use Gulp Browsersync with Django?

Tags: python, django, gulp, browser-sync, build-tools

First time using Gulp and I'm following a couple of tutorials that don't seem to be working quite right for me. I have a real basic project and I just want to learn how to use Gulp for standard things like JavaScript/CSS minification, image reduction, and browser sync.

When I run my watch task with Browsersync, it goes to the right URL of `localhost:8000`, but it shows `Cannot GET /` instead of rendering my page. How do I fix this so I can use Browsersync with Django?

File directory:

[image: http://screencast.com/t/AkIOE3TO]

`gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('polls/static/polls/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('polls/static/polls/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
});

gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: "mysite",
    port: 8000
  });
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sass'], function() {
  gulp.watch('polls/static/polls/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
})
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just had to make another task called `runserver` which runs in the cmd `python manage.py runserver`. Put the task as one of the dependencies for Browsersync, set the proxy and port, and I was set to go.

`var exec = require('child_process').exec` didn't require any extra `npm install`. I think it's automatically built in.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('polls/static/polls/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('polls/static/polls/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
});

gulp.task('runserver', function() {
  var proc = exec('python manage.py runserver')
})

gulp.task('browserSync', ['runserver'], function() {
  browserSync.init({
    notify: false,
    port: 8000,
    proxy: 'localhost:8000'
  })
});

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('browserSync', 'sass'), function() {
  gulp.watch('polls/static/polls/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('polls/static/polls/scripts/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('polls/templates/**/*.html', browserSync.reload);
})
```

Comment: Please be advised this syntax is no longer valid.  gulp.task has been depreciated and gulp.series or gulp.parallel should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Using Gulp 4, here is a copy of my code:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task('runserver', function() {
    var proc = exec('python manage.py runserver');
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log("HTTP Server Started");
        resolve();
    });
})

gulp.task('browserSync', gulp.series('runserver'), function() {
     browserSync.init({
         notify: false,
         port: 8000,
         proxy: 'localhost:8000'
     });
});

gulp.task('watch', gulp.series('browserSync'), function() {
    gulp.watch('polls/static/polls/scripts/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('polls/templates/**/*.html', browserSync.reload);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gulp.task('browserSync', ['runserver'], function() {
  browserSync.init({
    notify: false,
    proxy: 'localhost:8000'
  })
});
```

Comment: Code only answers are not good. Please add some explanation on how your code works.

Comment: I think you are missing the gulp task to run `python manage.py runserver` as a child process