# Browser Sync, npm, and Django Development Server

Tags: django, npm, browser-sync

I have been trying to resolve an error message when I run npm start on a Django project. I used [this tutorial by Keith Dechant](https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/instant-reload-django-npm-and-browsersync).

After spending a couple of hours duck-duck-going (searching) online :), I decided to ask you for help.  Here is the error message I get:

```
[0] npm WARN invalid config loglevel="notice"
[2] npm WARN invalid config loglevel="notice"
[0]
[0] > my_project@1.0.0 css-watch C:\Users\ED\Environments\my_project\my_project
[0] > node-sass my_project/static/scss -o my_project/static/css --watch
[0]
[2]
[2] > my_project@1.0.0 browser-sync C:\Users\ED\Environments\my_project\my_project
[2] > browser-sync start --files "my_project/static/css/*.css, my_project/static/js/*.js, my_project/**/*.py, my_project/templates/*.html" --proxy 127.0.0.1:8000 --reload-delay=300 --reload-debounce=500
[2]
[0] fs.js:994
[0]   binding.lstat(pathModule._makeLong(path), statValues);
[0]           ^
[0]
[0] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\ED\Environments\my_project\my_project\my_project\static\scss'
[0]     at Error (native)
[0]     at Object.fs.lstatSync (fs.js:994:11)
[0]     at Object.module.exports.parseDir (C:\Users\ED\Environments\my_project\my_project\node_modules\sass-graph\sass-graph.js:153:10)
[0]     at Object.watcher.reset (C:\Users\ED\Environments\my_project\my_project\node_modules\node-sass\lib\watcher.js:17:21)
[0]     at watch (C:\Users\ED\Environments\my_project\my_project\node_modules\node-sass\bin\node-sass:260:20)
[0]     at run (C:\Users\ED\Environments\my_project\my_project\node_modules\node-sass\bin\node-sass:319:5)
[0]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ED\Environments\my_project\my_project\node_modules\node-sass\bin\node-sass:405:3)
[0]     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
[0]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
[0]     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
[0] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[0] npm ERR! errno 1
[0] npm ERR! my_project@1.0.0 css-watch: `node-sass my_project/static/scss -o my_project/static/css --watch`
[0] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[0] npm ERR!
[0] npm ERR! Failed at the my_project@1.0.0 css-watch script.
[0] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[0]
[0] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[0] npm ERR!     C:\Users\ED\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-12T14_49_28_316Z-debug.log
[0] npm run css-watch exited with code 1
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
[1] python manage.py runserver exited with code 1
[2] npm run browser-sync exited with code 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my_project@1.0.0 start: `concurrently --kill-others "npm run css-watch" "python manage.py runserver" "npm run browser-sync" `
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my_project@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ED\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-12T14_49_28_559Z-debug.log
```

Has anyone run into a similar issue before?  Searching online did not land anywhere promising

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get browser sync to work when I utilized gulp.  Here are the steps:

- Install gulp as global using -g:

  ```
  npm install -g gulp
  ```
- Adding the following to gulpfile.js:

  ```
  var gulp = require('gulp');
  var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
  var sass = require('gulp-sass');
  var exec = require('child_process').exec;

  // Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers:
  gulp.task('sass', function() {
      return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'static/scss/*.scss'])
          .pipe(sass())
          .pipe(gulp.dest("static/css"))
          .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
  });


  // Play nice with Django development server
  gulp.task('runserver', function() {
      var proc = exec('python manage.py runserver 9000')
  });

  gulp.task('browserSync', ['runserver'], function() {
      browserSync.init({
          notify: false,
          port: 9000,
          proxy: 'localhost:9000'
      })

  });

  // Move the javascript files into our static/js folder
  gulp.task('js', function() {
      return gulp.src([ 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 'node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js'])
          .pipe(gulp.dest("static/js"))
          .pipe(browserSync.stream());


  });

  // Serving:
  gulp.task('serve', ['browserSync', 'sass'], function() {
      gulp.watch('static/scss/*.scss', ['sass']);
      gulp.watch('static/js/*.js', browserSync.reload);
      gulp.watch('templates/*.html', browserSync.reload);
  });

  gulp.task("default", function () {
    gulp.start("serve");
  });
  ```

Credit goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35590417/3549766) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40496420/3549766)